# How to use the image file name in redactor editor

Tags: php, javascript, redactor

while uploading an image in redactor editor, it itself rename the image file name with md5 encryption of current date and time. But i want to use the image file name.
You can see a live demo here: http://imperavi.com/redactor/ 
So, if a image file name is `bird.jpg` then i want to keep it as `bird.jpg` after upload it in editor, instead of something like this `e1cbe0be9c301f7f73f3271a86508db3.jpg`
**How Images upload Works:**
`redactor.js` file or by setting this option on load, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    $('#redactor_content').redactor({
        imageUpload: '/modules/upload.php'
    });
}
);
</script>
```

Let's assume that `upload.php` file will handle images. Its code may look like this:

```
<?php

// files storage folder
$dir = '/home/web/sitecom/redactor/images/';

$_FILES['file']['type'] = strtolower($_FILES['file']['type']);

if ($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/png'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg'
|| $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
{
// setting file's mysterious name
$file = $dir.md5(date('YmdHis')).'.jpg';

// copying
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file);

// displaying file
$array = array(
    'filelink' => '/images/'.$file
);

echo stripslashes(json_encode($array));
}

?>
```

JSON example:

```
{ "filelink": "/images/img.jpg" }
```

so how to keep the `$file` to be the image name instead of the md5 data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in upload.php

> $file = $dir.md5(date('YmdHis')).'.jpg';

to

> $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

you get the file name in `$file`

for more reference you can check docs at
http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/files/